# A clue to solve this equation

Tags: calculus

how to prove that if $f(x,y)=0$ and $g(x,z)=0$ and if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable,then:

$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}.\dfrac {\partial g}{\partial x}dy=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}.\dfrac {\partial g}{\partial z}dz$$

I think $y$ and  $z$ should be dependent, however there is no mentioning for that in the question.

Comment: Your title does not reflect the question.

Comment: $y$ and $z$ are obviously dependent as they are both dependent on $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy=0,\\
\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x}dx+\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial z}dz=0.$$

Then eliminating $dx$,

$$\frac{\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}}{\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}}dy=\frac{\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial z}}{\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x}}dz.$$

Comment: So you used that df and dg are zeros, not the functions themselves.

Comment: @Fifi: the functions do not appear in the requested identity !